# Sort users by userID by default on users.php

Tags: users

I want to sort users by User ID on `users.php` by default. The page is currently ordered by `username` as default.

Is there any hook to alter the `order_by` option on `users.php` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pre_get_users` since WP 4.0.0

```
function my_user_sort( $query_args ){
    if( is_admin() && !isset($_GET['orderby']) ) {
        $query_args->query_vars['orderby'] = 'ID';
    }
    return $query_args;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'my_user_sort' );
```

Comment: You can probably change the if condition to `if( !isset($_GET['orderby']) ) {`. I didn't confirm whether `pre_get_users` is called anywhere other than admin.

Comment: `if( is_admin() && !isset($_GET['orderby']) )` condition is fine for me, since I only need this on admin. I think this is called anywhere, when the users query is called. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Nice! Now how would you add descending order to that function, so that the most recent users appear on top?